# How to make a java class that replaces every instance of the string "is" with "is not"?

Tags: java, replace

How to make a java class that replaces every instance of the string "is" with "is not"?

```
public class Notreplace {

    public String notReplace(String){
        String i = " is ";
        String o = i.replaceAll(" is "," is not ");
    }
    void main(){

        String a = "is it";
        notReplace(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Fix it first so it has a chance to even compile.

Comment: I´d recomment to read through a basic java tutorial, there are multiple syntacticle mistakes in there.

Comment: Maybe you should go to this site to learn more java 
http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are severals errors in your code.

1. You do not use the parameter you send to the function
2. You do not return a value and store it in a variable
3. You try to replace `_is_` in a String which does not contain space (`_` around `is` means spaces).

So this code should work (not tested)

```
public static String notReplace(String s){
    return s.replaceAll("is","is not");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String oldValue = "is it";
    String newValue = notReplace(oldValue);
}
```

**EDIT** based on @Andreas comment.

The method above can cause issue if in your String you have a word whith the substring `is`. For example

```
is this a plane ?
```

will become

```
is not this not a plane ?
```

To solve this issue you must use regexp and replace you method by

```
public static String notReplace(String s){
    return s.replaceAll("\\b([Ii]s)\\b(?!\\s+not\\b)", "$1 not");
}
```

Where

> \\b prevents letters is embedded in a word from being replaced, ([Ii]s) combined with $1 will allow matching a leading uppercase letter, and the (?!\\s+not\\b) prevents adding not if it's already there

Comment: It should be `replaceAll("\\b([Ii]s)\\b(?!\\s+not\\b)", "$1 not")`, where `\\b` prevents letters `is` embedded in a word from being replaced, `([Ii]s)` combined with `$1` will allow matching a leading uppercase letter, and the `(?!\\s+not\\b)` prevents adding `not` if it's already there.

Comment: You are right. Can I include it in the answer ? Or you want to put it in your own answer ?

Comment: @Andreas the OP doesn't know how to write a simple method like that, therefore i think it might be a bit too much to introduce him into the world of regexes!

Comment: @Maloubobola Please embed in your answer. You already have my up-vote.

Comment: @ParkerHalo The right regex to do the job is not just for OP, it's for everybody else looking for an answer to a question like that.

Comment: @Andreas that's a noble thought but still this answer should primarily help the OP shouldn't it? And it will quite sure confuse him if you confront him with things like regexes.

Comment: I would make a small note at the end mentioning the improved regex code

Answer (score 1):

Try it more like this:

```
/**
 * StringReplaceDemo
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 11/24/2015
 * Time: 8:21 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893724/im-trying-to-make-a-java-class-that-replaces-every-instance-of-the-string-is/33894815#33894815
 */
public class StringReplaceDemo {

    public static String replaceAllSnippets(String orig, String snippetToReplace, String replacementSnippet) {
        String result = orig;
        if ((orig != null) && (orig.length() > 0)) {
            result = orig.replaceAll(snippetToReplace,replacementSnippet);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(String.format("orig: '%s' replaced: '%s'", arg, StringReplaceDemo.replaceAllSnippets(arg, "\\s+is\\s+", " is not ")));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest working throuh one of the many tutorials you can find in the web! For now i can tell you some things that went wrong:

1. the method `notReplace(String)` is missing the name for the string variable.
2. If you want to call this method from the main method it has to be declared static.

You should declare your method as:

```
public static String notReplace(String replaceAt) { ... }
```

3. Take a look at what you're replacing: `.replaceAll(" is "," is not ");`. You might want to change this to `.replaceAll("is","is not");` in order to find all occurencies of "is" even when there's no space nearby.
4. You want to replace something at the String `replaceAt`, not at any local String (like the `String i = ...` you defined). Change `i.replaceAll("is", "is not");` with `replaceAt.replaceAll("is", "is not");`
5. Using the method `notReplace()` without assigning it to the previous declared String won't change anything!

Change:

```
notReplace(a);
```

to

```
a = notReplace(a);
```

---

Regarding everything your code should look like this:

```
public class Notreplace {

    public static String notReplace(String replaceAt){
        return replaceAt.replaceAll("is", "is not");
    }

    void main(){
        String a = "is it";
        a = notReplace(a);
    }
}
```